# is it possible to make calls in qpython

Tags: qpython, qpython3

im making an alexa like artificial intelligence/virtual assistant and have already added the ability to send texts, but cant figure out how to call. i found a post on how to make a notification when you get one, but not the ability to actally send them. is this even possible in qpython? thanks

example code:

```
response = input("enter command: ")   
if response[1] == "call":  
   *call function* (response[2])
```

outcome:

```
enter command: call 123456789    
calling 123456789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a call with this code.
Insert phone number with country code as  input of response

```
from androidhelper import Android
droid = Android()
response=input ("Enter phone number here:")
droid.phoneCallNumber (response)
```

Comment: Why do you delete and then post the exact same answer?

Comment: You can undelete questions.

Comment: Because this is my first time which I answered a question. So I saw my first answer is not clear. Actually both answers are same, in first answer I couldn't put the code as a code.But this code is clear. And I'm sure it will work well because it worked for me!